# Android Apk Submission target

Tags: android, target-sdk, targetsdkversion

I tried to submit my updated application to playstore. When I tried upload the apk on production, there was notice saying

> Play Store will require that new apps and app
>   updates target a recent Android API level. This will be required for
>   new apps in August 2018, and for updates to existing apps in November
>   2018. This is to ensure apps are built on the latest APIs optimized for security and performance.

Currently, my application was set minSDKVersion 19 and targetSDKVersion as 23.

Does that mean I have to update my application to targetSDKVersion 26?

I have tried to change this and upload it. I seems to have error saying about the downgrade (Sorry I should have make a note of the message).

Comment: The downgrade error isn't because your are uploading your app decreasing your Version Number?

Comment: What is exactly "to have error about the downgrade"? Can you upload the complete error message?

Comment: I forgot to make note of that message. Is the targetSDKversion to be changed according to that quotes.

Comment: It is just a warning for now, it doesn't block anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does that mean I have to update my application to targetSDKVersion 26?

Yes. But for now its just a warning, it will enforced from beginning of August for new apps. Do take note that deadline for app update is November.

> have tried to change this and upload it. I seems to have error saying
>   about the downgrade

Since you don't have complete error message, one probable cause of this issue is, you are trying to upload an app which has VersionCode less than the app available on play store. Re-check your version code and increase it if needed.

Comment: Maybe that is the cause.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> August 2018: New apps required to target API level 26 (Android 8.0) or
>    higher.
>
> November 2018: Updates to existing apps required to target API level 26 or higher.
>
> 2019 onwards: Each year the targetSdkVersion
>   requirement will advance. Within one year following each Android
>   dessert release, new apps and app updates will need to target the
>   corresponding API level or higher.

source: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/12/improving-app-security-and-performance.html